# How to update a multi-picklist on contact/lead based on a campaign field?

Tags: leads, contact, campaign, multi-select

I am trying to update a multipicklist on lead/contact object after they become members of a campaign (of a certain record type). The campaign has a multipicklist with certains values and I want to add these values to the multipicklist of the lead/contact without deleting the values that were already stored in the field previously.